# Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6235 Bluetooth 4.0 with Headset

Tags: bluetooth, headset

I have a Samsung Laptop running Windows 7 x64 with a Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6235 Bluetooth 4.0 radio which I have paired with a Motorola Razor Bluetooth headset.

Whenever the the headset connects it chooses the VOIP profile rather than the Music profile be default which makes for a less than ideal listening experience.

[image: Connection Profile]

I need to disconnect and reconnect to the Music profile to get the audio quality I expect.

I have tried to stop it connecting to VOIP without success is there any way to make it connect to Music by default rather than VOIP?

Also on my previous setup the headset buttons could be used to control a music player however with the new Laptop this does not work.

I am running the latest 2.2.0 drivers.